# how to encrypt a portion of html data

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to encrypt html data before saving in Database.
this is a sample html text:

```
<p>test data in normal text</p> <p><b>test data in bold text</b></p> <p><i>test data in italics text</i></p> <p><b><i>test data in bold and italics text</i></b><br></p>
```

Can anyone help me to find a solution.

Comment: What kind of encryption are you looking for? Either way, this is very easily researched if you make the effort.

Comment: We might need a _little_ more information on this one...

Comment: I tried plain text for encryption.But i want to encrypt html data (For eg: <p>test data in normal text</p> <p><b>test data in bold text</b>) before saving in database.

Answer (score 1):

use can use OpenSSL encrypt

```
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    //store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
```

check following link for more detail
http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php